# Exit a thread during sleep/wait

Tags: multithreading

Is it possible in any language to kill a thread while it is sleeping/waiting?

My scenario:
I have two threads, one is constantly looking for a rising edge in a data stream, lets call it EdgeThread, and one is setting variables based off the difference between rising edges, lets call it DifThread. The main program is plotting this data.

If EdgeThread detects another rising edge before DifThread finishes setting its variables (sleeping .5 seconds between each variable change), DifThread needs to immediately stop and relaunch, even if it is sleeping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Languages like Java or any of the languages in the .NET platform support some form of thread wait/notify mechanism.

The idea is that instead of simply having the thread `sleep` for a period of time, you have the thread `wait` on an object to be signaled while specifying a timeout period on the waiting time, effectively behaving similarly to a `sleep`.

Here is a very contrived example inspired by your requirement description that illustrates how the mechanism works using .NET/C# (you can try out this little example yourself):

```cs
private static readonly object objLock = new object();
private static volatile bool shouldIRelaunch = false;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Thread difThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        while (!shouldIRelaunch)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("difThread - doing some work...");

            // Now, instead of sleeping, perform a wait which a pulse can interrupt.
            lock (objLock)
            {
                Monitor.Wait(objLock, 500);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("difThread - Exiting thread...");
    });

    Thread edgeThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("edgeThread - sleeping for a few seconds...");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        lock (objLock)
        {
            shouldIRelaunch = true;
            Monitor.Pulse(objLock);
            Console.WriteLine("edgeThread - Notiying difThread thread to interrupt the wait");
        }
    });

    difThread.Start();
    edgeThread.Start();
}
```

The above code snippet produces the following output:

```
difThread - doing some work...
edgeThread - sleeping for a few seconds...
difThread - doing some work...
difThread - doing some work...
difThread - doing some work...
difThread - doing some work...
difThread - doing some work...
difThread - doing some work...
difThread - doing some work...
difThread - doing some work...
difThread - doing some work...
edgeThread - Notiying difThread thread to interrupt the wait
difThread - Exiting thread...
```

Relevant documentation for .NET languages: [Monitor.Wait()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/syehfawa(v=vs.110).aspx), [Monitor.Pulse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulse(v=vs.110).aspx).

For Java: [Guarded Blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html)

---

Java also has the notion of interrupting a sleep that may be of interest to you.  See here for more information: [Interrupts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html)

Comment: This is exactly what i'm looking for. I prefer python, so i'll check to see if there is a similar implementation there, if not I'll rewrite to java.